# How to run Mule 3.5.3 as non root

Tags: mule

I am facing issues while trying to run mule 3.5.3 as non root user in docker container. It works fine when the root user is used.

The Mule startup process is creating a file tx1.log during startup, this file does not have any permissions and later during the startup it tries to read this file which leads to (java.io.FileNotFoundException - Permission denied).

The file location is **/.mule/.agent/queue-tx-log/tx1.log**.

I also tried with ***umask*** 777 added to /mule and /launcher scripts, but it did not help.

Is there a do's and dont's for running mule as non root?

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

note: chown and chmod have been used where ever I felt necessary necessary.

Comment: I suspect `/.mule` is a volume mount, right? And what does "does not have any permissions" even mean? Of course it has permissions, even if they are that no one can read or write the file

Comment: when I do ls -ltra in queue-tx-log folder , I see this:
---------- 1 user1 group1 0 2019-04-09 02:22 tx1.log

I am not explicitly doing any volume mount.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel This is not really a kubernetes question. It is a mule question. I have removed kubernetes and docker from the tags list. You should not downvote without understanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

Mule runs perfectly well as non root and that is the recommendation because of security best practices. The only issue I have seen is if it is started as root first, it creates files with root ownership, then a non privileged user is not able to use those files.

From the comments I can see that the problem seems to be on the operating system or docker/kubernetes. Mule just doesn't do weird things with permissions.

Aside that, note that Mule  3.5.x will reach it's end of life sat July 15, 2019. I recommend to migrate to a newer version.

Comment: It was just a umask issue. found it after a hunt.